# Cursor move appearing itself

Tags: css, laravel, cursor

Hi there can anyone help me with this problem that I am facing, in my code there is not anything that would make the cursor:move, but when I go to page there appears the drag cursor, and when I look with inspect element it appears inside for example  a `<p style="cursor:move"> </p>` but this style in code it is not can anyone help me please to remove this.
Thank you

Comment: Could you show us a link or put your code on [Codepen](https://codepen.io)?

Comment: Since you have nothing inside your `<p>` tag, it might not have any height. Give some height.

Answer (score 2):

**Since your `<p>` tag is empty, it has no `height` (or no content area for the mouse to hover over).** Add some height to get some space to show the cursor. I have added a snippet with `<p>` having border to show that the content space is not there to show the cursor.

```css
p {border: 1px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
<p style="cursor: pointer;"></p>
```

**Solution**

1. Using `&nbsp;`.
2. Using `height` or `padding`.

Demonstrated the above three techniques in the below snippet.

```css
p {border: 1px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
<p style="cursor: pointer;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="cursor: pointer; height: 10px;"></p>
<p style="cursor: pointer; padding: 10px;"></p>
```